# How to get opened modal elements using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

Is there any way to get an opened **modal** using javascript? I don't know any *id*, *class name*, *tag name*, or ... but when I trigger an event of an element in a web site, a modal will popup. Now the question is: How can I get the 'div' or any element in this opened modal? Consider that, there is many hidden elements in the html body and when the event dispatches, these appear.

Comment: If you really don't know anything to recognize a pop-up, I'm afraid you can't do anything.

Comment: Since you're saying you have basically no way to select the element, you might want to look at [elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)

Comment: @S.Strempfer Do you know How can I find root element of opened modal using elementFromPoint() ? I mean, Which parentNode is the root in opened modal?

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea what your HTML looks like

Comment: Take a look at the source code, find the event handler which opens a modal. That handler should contain something with which it refers to the modal it opens. You should be able to use the same reference, unless the modals are created on the fly. Even then you can find the parent element and something to refer to, if not else, some unique content.